# What is the etymology of the South American use of the word "boliche" to mean disco/club?

Tags: etimología

As far as I can see the word *boliche* relates to balls and the game of bowling. In mexico it refers to a bowling alley, but in South American countries it refers to a disco or a club.

But then there is a strange parallel with the english word "ball" meaning a dancing party, which supposedly comes from the latin *ballare* "to dance".. so nothing to do with balls.

I'm guessing this is just a coincidence, but regardless, it's strange that boliche came to refer to a disco. Is there any information out there about how that came to be the case?

Answer (score 3):

**Boliche** has been in the Spanish language since the 17th century with the meaning of "gambling house". It derives from the Catalan **bolitx**, a type of small net for fishing, since money was "fished" in gambling houses (a metaphor). In turn, *bolitx* derives from the Greek *bolídion*, which is the diminutive of *bólos*, "a net".

Supported by the other word *bola* ("ball"), the meaning then specialized in the bowling game. But it also passed to America at the end of the 19th century, mainly in the language of criminals, to refer to clandestine places where you could gamble and drink alcohol. Hence, in Argentina, Uruguay and Chile it has been used to refer to taverns, then to bad class stores where alcohol is sold, and finally, due to a mixture of irony, metonymy and a sense of humor, to neighborhood stores and nightclubs.

Answer (score 1):

**Boliche**, es un diminutivo que procede del griego **βολη**, lanzamiento, disparo, **βολις**, proyectil, **βολος**, acción de lanzar. Estas palabras dieron lugar a palabras como bola, bolo (con el significado de piedra), bolera o bala entre otras.

En general la palabra "**Boliche**" se relaciona con las piedras, así una playa de boliches o bolos, se entiende que es una playa en donde abundan las piedras, también se vincula con los bolos y la bolera, pues es una "bola" que se "lanza" a modo de una "piedra". El "boliche" es igualmente un antiguo juego que consiste en introducir una bola agujereada en un palo, al que está unido mediante una cuerda.

La palabra inglesa "**ball**" con el significado de "bailar", es un préstamo del antiguo griego, **βάλλω**, y que tomo el latín "ballare", de aquí se extendió a las diferentes lenguas. La antigua palabra "**βάλλω**" griega, tiene entre sus acepciones, a parte de "lanzar", también de "echar", y como verbo se utilizaba en el sentido de "echar", "echar los brazos en torno o alrededor de alguien", aunque no estuvieran completamente pegados o abrazados, de ahí la evolución de la palabra "**bailar**", y no "danzar" (latín: salto).

**Boliche** puede ser entendido como un nombre comercial, nombre muy utilizado en algunas partes de España, preferentemente en la costa, que puede hacer referencia a un sitio de bolos o piedras, también "bolo", en el sentido de lugar de ocio y actuaciones o simple casualidad en su elección por ser un nombre sonoro.

Por último en **Iberoamérica** en algunos lugares como Argentina, llamaban **boliches** antiguamente a los comercios a los que solían acudir criollos, indígenas o inmigrantes para proveerse de existencias o productos y donde era habitual consumir bebidas alcohólicas o ser un lugar de entretenimiento, esparcimiento, ocio y juegos de azar.

Quizás el nombre que mencionas de "**Boliche**" con cierto significado para *Discotecas o Clubs*, puede estar basado en este último y más actual sentido Iberoamericano de la palabra "**Boliche**".